# Git debug custom merge driver

Tags: node.js, git, merge

I am working on creating a custom merge driver. Everything seems to be working under a number of use cases; however, in one specific one I am getting during a merge: "fatal: custom merge driver users lacks command line." which I can only assume means that my custom merge driver is exiting with something other than a 0.

I am programming the merge driver in node.js and it is installed as a global package on my machine. The .gitconfig and .gitattributes seem to be setup right since the merge driver is being used when I expect it to.

When I was doing my own testing (manually specifying 3 files) I was console.log some debug information, but it seems that during runtime with GIT merge these console messages are supressed. Is there anyway that I can see some of this debug information from my custom merge driver as git is actually using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR summary

You must have, in some Git configuration file(s), at least two lines that read, e.g.:

```
[merge "users"]
    any-variable-not-named-driver = any-value
```

but *without* a previous or subsequent line (in the same section of the same Git config file) of the form:

```
    driver = some string, preferably with %-escapes
```

Note that when anyone (including an external program) runs `git somecommand`, there are up to three such configuration files read. One is system-wide (usually `/etc/gitconfig`), so that all users on any given machine see the same file with the same contents.  One file is per-user, found in `$HOME/.gitconfig` or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`.  The last file is per-repository, found in `$GIT_DIR/config`, where `$GIT_DIR` defaults to the first `.git` directory at or above the current working directory.

You must also have, in a `.gitattributes` file, at least one line that reads:

```
name-or-pattern    merge=users
```

And you must then invoke a merge that involves a file pathname that matches the name-or-pattern on the left.

#### Explanation

The message itself comes from [`ll-merge.c` around line 192](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0aaa1b6532cfce93d87af9bc813fb2e7a7ce9d7/ll-merge.c#L191-L192):

> ```
> if (fn->cmdline == NULL)
>     die("custom merge driver %s lacks command line.", fn->name);
> ```

(Incidentally, "ll" here stands for "low level": this is the "low level merge" code, with low level merges being done on a per-file basis.)
  Due to other error checking, this particular condition—`fn->cmdline == NULL`—can only occur if there at least one occurrence of `merge.users.whatever` in any of the config files Git has read.  (You could get some other errors in various other cases, but those are not the <s>droids you are looking for</s> errors you are seeing.)

Remember that there are three such files (system, global, and local).  They are read in that order: system first, then global, then local.  Any or all three of these files can contain lines that partially or completely define a custom merge driver; the settings from all three files get applied, in whatever order they occur, with later settings generally overriding earlier settings.

This is *how and why* local settings generally override global settings.  There are a few cases where settings accumulate, rather than overriding.  For custom merge drivers, the overall effect is a weird hybrid: the *drivers*—the *`name`* part from `merge.name.whatever`—accumulate, but the individual *settings*—the *`whatever`* part for any one given `merge.name.whatever`—get overridden, if they occur more than once!

Next, see [`read_merge_config()`, lines 232-296 of the same file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e0aaa1b6532cfce93d87af9bc813fb2e7a7ce9d7/ll-merge.c#L232-L296): these mean that whenever `merge.users.whatever` is read, a data structure of type `struct ll_merge_driver` is created if necessary, or—if it exists—the existing one with name `users` is re-used.  The variable `fn` points to this structure; `fn->name` is `users` and `fn->fn` is `ll_ext_merge()` (the latter is the C code function that invokes an external merge driver, and is where the quoted two lines above are found).

Some of the remaining lines in `read_merge_config()` check whether the *`whatever`* is the literal string `name` or `driver`.  For the latter case (`driver`), the code fills in the `fn->cmdline` field with the specified value.

To get `ll_ext_merge()` itself called at all with `users` as the name of the user-defined merge driver, these three conditions must be satisfied:

- You have run (directly or indirectly) `git merge` or a command that invokes a merge (such as `git cherry-pick` or `git revert` or `git rebase` or `git apply -3`, for instance);
- Based on all three inputs (the merge base and the two tip commits), some file *F* requires a full three-way "low level" merge because it has three different hash IDs in the three inputs; and
- The `.gitattributes` for file *F* includes the line `merge=users`.

At this time (and at no other time), Git actually calls `ll_ext_merge`, passing it the data structure created and filled in (whether partially or completely) while reading the three Git configuration files (system, global, and local).

Since you now get the error message that you got, we know:

- There existed, in the three configuration files, at least one occurrence of `merge.users.whatever`, but
- None of the `whatever`s was `driver`.

This is how I reached the conclusion at the top of this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also feel a little silly. It appears that I had the word "drive" instead of "driver" in my gitconfig. How much of a difference one letter makes. So the times when I thought it was working it wasn't even being used. oh well. all is well now. Thank you so much for your help. I even see my console.log output.

Comment: @SeanW.: interesting; I was supposing that maybe there were different config files involved, so that it worked when run one way (with one user's global config) and not when run another (with some other user's global config). Since the `.gitattributes` and `.gitconfig` and/or `.git/config` files are all separate, it is easy to get them out of sync.